# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type View

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, spinner, android-spinner

I am getting the following error on the line of code:

**Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type View**

```
mspinner        = (Spinner) View.findViewById(R.id.spinnervdc);
```

Also the following error on the line of code

**The constructor ArrayAdapter(ListViewFragment, int, String[]) is undefined**

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);
```

And my MainActivity is

```
package com.yogeshojha.nagariksahayata;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.yogeshojha.nagariksahayata.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener{
public ListViewFragment(){}
Spinner mspinner; //declare spinner globally
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

mspinner        = (Spinner) View.findViewById(R.id.spinnervdc);
//set adapter for spinner here
String [] name = {"A","B","C"};
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);
// you can use getActivity() or this 

mspinner.setAdapter(adapter);

return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {

//do something when particular item is selected from spinner

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use View. Instead, use rootView.

```
mSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnervdc);
```

**Update**

Your class extends Fragment class, not an Activity class. Therefore when you use **this**, it causes the second error you mentioned.

You need to give the activity as parameter to the arrayadapter constructor; just as Raghunandan suggests.

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);
```

**Update 2**

This might be helpful to others who get similar errors. You cannot benefit more from anything else than looking at the class references.

Here, [in the document,](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29) it says that the first parameter had to be a Context. Your way is not included in any overloaded versions of the constructor. That is why you get the *undefined constructor* error.

Answer (score 3):

try this way

```
mspinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnervdc);
```

instead of

```
mspinner = (Spinner) View.findViewById(R.id.spinnervdc);
```

Your `Spinner` is coming from the `rootView layout`, so you need to initialize it using that particular layout.

and also you should change this

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);
```

with

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);
```

Comment: @YogeshOjha use `getActivity()` instead of `this`. `this` is not a valid context

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the already suggest answer

```
mspinner= (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnervdc);
```

As the error says

> The constructor ArrayAdapter(ListViewFragment, int, String[]) is
>   undefined

`this` refers to `ListViewFragment` which extends `Fragment`. You need a valid context. So use `getActivity()`.

This

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);
```

Should be

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are making a refrence of

```
View **rootView** = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);
```

you have to access ell the widgets on this reference like below.

```
mspinner = (Spinner) rootView .findViewById(R.id.spinnervdc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change:

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);
```

to

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

mspinner        = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnervdc);
//set adapter for spinner here
String [] name = {"A","B","C"};
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);


mspinner.setAdapter(adapter);

return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

findViewByID() is not an static method so you cannot call it like this  try this
`mSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnervdc);`

and for this `adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);`
try this  `adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);`

Hope this will work